express-http-proxy resets connection when transfter-enconding header is set to chunked
I have a very basic usecase where I'm proxy requests to example.com to def.com using express-http-proxy module. Code is straightforward as shown in the documentation.
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var app = require('express')();

app.use('/proxy', proxy('https://def.com'));

This works as expected when the request is sent as,
curl  -v https://example.com/proxy/getdata.
But if the request is sent as following, then the proxy library appears to immediately reset the request to the client with status as 504 Gateway Timeout and a response header set as "x-timeout-reason: express-http-proxy reset the request".
curl -v -H "transfer-encoding: chunked" https://example.com/proxy/getdata
The transfer-encoding request header is set by the gateway in certain scenarios. Our app has no control over that.
I'm trying to understand why express-http-proxy is closing connection and what I can do to fix this issue.
